# Is it normal that I need u+w to set extended filesystem attributes?

Tags: python, xattr

I noticed that on [panfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panasas#PanFS), Python's `copystat` fails when the source file does not have the `u+w` permission bit set; setting attributes fails with `Permission denied` command line equivalent: (`attr_set: Permission denied`).

Considering that for "normal" files on "normal" filesystems, file ownership is enough to change attributes, I wonder if panfs is being unreasonable, or if this is something the calling application (in this case Python's `copystat` or a higher level function) should be expected to catch.

What are the normal requirements for the ability to set extended file attributes?  Is panfs unreasonable?  Or should I file with the Python folk that they should catch this?

It's causing [pip install to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31119022/974555), so it's a rather annoying problem in practice.

See also [this Python bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue24538).